# Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code in Android Studio - Flutter

Tags: flutter, xcode, android-studio, ios-simulator

I've updated my macOS to Sonoma version 14.1, and updated flutter to the latest version, and updated Xcode to 15.0.1 but when I want to run on iOS simulator using `iPhone 15 Pro Max - iOS 17.0`, on Android Studio it shows this Error:

> Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit
> code
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

But when I run the project using Xcode everything is fine and can run in a right way but has problem in Android Studio.

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on macOS 
14.1 23B74 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)

[✓] Network resources
```

Android Studio:

Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days searching and trying different ways, I solved the problem.
you can read this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/137485) to see what I've done.